# C++ retrieving pointer from stack

Tags: c++

I have class with this format:

```
class polarity {
public:
    void method1();
    void method2();


    polarity();
    ~polarity();
private:

    stack<type*>  carbon;
    vector<scientist*>   sci;

};
```

here is method1:

```
void polarity::method1(){

    type * object1;
    object1 = new type();
    unsigned int i;


        for(i = 0; i <carbon.size() ; ++i){         
            object1 = carbon.pop();
            /*Do something with object1*/
        }
}
```

when I run the program I receive this error

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'type *'
```

I do not understand what it means. I just fill stack with some pointer of type. but I cannot retrieve these pointer.
I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: What is `type`?

Comment: it is another object.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `std::stack`... A quick search will tell you what the `top()` and the `pop()` functions do.

Comment: IMO, `type` is a poor naming choice for a data structure.

Comment: would you please specify which one?

Comment: This is C++, so why are you using `operator new`, as in `object1 = new type();`?

Comment: You have a memory leak in `method1`.  You allocate memory, then the pointer to that memory area is replaced inside the loop.  Bad, very bad.

Comment: what is you suggestion?

Comment: Storing raw pointers in STL containers is generally a bad idea anyway, it's best not to do it. Use `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<type>>` if you really need pointer behaviour in your container.

Answer (score 4):

The method pop from `stack` return a `void` because only pop out the element from the stack maybe you looking for `carbon.top()` but I don't know what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

`pop()` function is a void function:

```
void pop();
```

> Removes the top element from the stack. Effectively calls c.pop_back().

Therefore when you assign a `type*` to a function returning `void`, you get that error.

As you can see here:

```
  object1 = carbon.pop();
```

when you pop `carbon` you return a `void` , which is not of type `type`. Hence getting the error :

> Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'type *'

Look **[here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop)** for refrence

### Solution

You are looking for `top()` . so now you can do :

```
  object1 = carbon.top();
```

Look **[here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top)** for refrence about `top()`.

Comment: Can someone please explain why the downvote, So i can improve my answer? Thankyou